# Multiple Linear Regression Model - ValueError: X has 6 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 22 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have fitted a Linear Regression model using sklearn in python using 22 columns of training data in order to predict market prices. See below:

```
#X_train is our training values to predict y
X_train = updatedTrainingData.drop(['DateTime','ISEMDA_GBP'], axis=1)
y_train = updatedTrainingData['ISEMDA_GBP'].values

#Setting up the linear regression model:
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()

#Passing the data to the model object's .fit() method:
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Getting Meteo Forecast data to make the predictions on. I.e, based on these values, what is 
the price
Meteo = sp_MeteoForecastData(startDate='20221019', endDate='20221020', auction='DAM')

#Aligning it with DA times
predictionValues = Meteo.loc[(Meteo['DateTime'] >= '2022-10-19 23:00') & (Meteo['DateTime'] <= 
'2022-10-20 22:00')]

#Dropping Datetime and Auction as these have no bearing on Price
selectedPredictionValues = predictionValues.drop(['DateTime','Auction'], axis=1)

forecastedDAPrices = model.predict(selectedPredictionValues)
```

But when I call model.predict on selectedPredictionValues, I get the following error:

> ValueError: X has 6 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 22 features as input.

I understand I have fitted the model with 22 columns of training data, and I'm trying to make a prediction with only 6. Is there anyway way to handle this so I can train the model with 22 columns but only use 6 to make predictions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want that....? Part of the idea behind these types of models is to assume the test data comes from a similar distribution as your training data. If you fit a model to 22 features, your model learns to weigh those features. If you suddenly remove most of those features to test on, you're going against the purpose of your training. So if you only want 6 features for prediction, only use 6 for training.

Comment: @Chrispresso This is the conclusion I came to upon sleeping on it. Very new to ML!! Thanks for your feedback.